# Backbone.js Work with server response to save() method

Tags: backbone.js

I'm kind of new to Backbone. I need use the data in the server response to a save() method but I'm not sure how to get it. This is the code:

```
$(".act_btn").on("click", function(){
    var act_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    startRecordItem = new StartRecordItem({
        activity: act_id,
    });
    startRecordItem.save({ 
        success: function(response){console.log(response)}
        });

    /*
    recordItem = new RecordItem({
        id: ... <---- I have to populate this with the data from the server response.
    });
   */
```

Right now the success function doesn't work at all, what am I missing? I'd like to get an attribute from the JSON response and then use it on the ´new RecordItem´. The save itself works correctly and the response looks like this:

```
{"activity": 1, "id": 14}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that the first argument of `.save`. is the attributes that get passed into the model, pre-save. You want to do something more like this:

```
startRecordItem.save(null, {
  success: function(response) { 
    console.log(response); 
  }
});
```

Since Backbone fires a `sync` event on successful save, you could also do this:

`this.listenTo(startRecordItem, 'sync', function() { /* logic here */ });`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One small question, if I use the event listener `listenTo(startRecordItem, 'sync', function() ..` how can I pass response data to the function?

Comment: @alejoss great! The function you pass into `listenTo` for `sync` is called by Backbone with 3 arguments: `model, response, options`. You can use those arguments to get at the response data.